# node http2 and safari

Tags: node.js, safari, http2

I am well into building an single page application using nodejs and the http2 module.  The client end is using Polymer and is a progressive web app, with a fairly minimal index.html.  I have been doing most of the development in chrome, and am reasonably happy, since this is an intranet application and I can dictate the brower.

I would like to support the ipad, albeit perhaps at lesser performance.  I have to borrow my wife's if want to try anything, and I couldn't get it to work at all.  I do have a mac laptop and tried accessing my (in development) site using safari on that (I also have chrome on it and that works fine).  With Safari it doesn't get anywhere.  In fact with the web inspector open it doesn't even appear to have loaded the basic index.html file.

I am assuming that safari doesn't support http2.  I am not sure what I should do about it through.  How do you gracefully fall back to something else?

Answer (score 0):

Safari does support http/2. Test your site at https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/ and see if you've a cipher config that safari supports.